# Parse Firefox HSTS Preloading list

Tags: firefox, ssl, hsts

I need to parse the Mozilla's HSTS preloading list Which is mentioned on the dveloper forum of Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/HTTP_strict_transport_security

as "Consultation of the Firefox HSTS preload list : https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mozilla/security/manager/ssl/nsSTSPreloadList.inc " Please explain the format and comments mentioned in this file.

Chrome provides HSTS preloading list in JSON format which is self explanatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nsSTSPreloadList.inc` is C++ code, generated from [chromium/src/net/+/master/http/transport_security_state_static.json](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/http/transport_security_state_static.json).

The code that generates it is: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/tools/getHSTSPreloadList.js -- you can figure out the output format from that.

BTW, the format of the generated file [was recently changed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1255425), so the answer will depend on what version of Firefox you're interested in.

With the current format, it looks like you can extract the comments that look like this: `/* hostname, true */` - and be done with it.

Comment: what does the boolean value means in this  /* hostname, true */. That is matter of confusion for me 
Because there is one more array kSTSPreloadList[] which has index of hostname with isIncludeSubdomain support flag.
And thanks your answer helped a lot.

Comment: I think the boolean is the value of `includeSubdomain`. You're looking at the latest version of this code [that was optimized for memory use](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1255425), hence the two arrays - one holding the domain name, the other holding the bit flag. The boolean value from the comment is duplicated in the second array. [Here's](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/90b96acae18a/security/manager/ssl/nsSTSPreloadList.inc) how the list looked before the optimization.

Comment: Yes it is includeSubdomain flag. Thanks, getHSTSPreloadList.js file helped me figure out exact format. !!